# Symfony Many to Many returns empty ArrayCollection

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have two entities Product and Part, connected by a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Part
{
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product",
    mappedBy="parts", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
class Product
{
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Part", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_parts",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="part_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $parts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getParts()
    {
        return $this->parts;
    }

    /**
     * @param $parts
     */
    public function setParts($parts)
    {
        $this->parts = $parts;
    }
}
```

When I try get single Product and show all related parts. Symfony returns an empty array. Although the data is correctly added to the database. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: After adding fetch = "EAGER" works :)

Comment: fetch=EAGER implies that you are looking at the raw entity, possible using the dump function.  $products->getParts(); should kick off an LAZY load.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I suggested that there is no data in the dump

Comment: The thing about adding fetch=EAGER is that parts will always be eagerly loaded even in cases where you don't need them.  As an alternative, you can write a custom DQL query, explicitly join the parts and then use the query whenever you know you need the parts.